# get image from https url+iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to get the image from https url in iphone:-
The url is like this:-

https://staging.api.botentekoop.nl/image.ashx?ID=804306&imagesize=Normal&imagetype=MainImage

i had done some google work and found the help from this link:-
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5511-load-image-internet.html
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/80894-load-image-url.html

But there all example is shown for http not from https

CAn anyone help me.
please how to do this

Answer (score 0):

The URL Loading System on iOS works the same for HTTP and HTTPS URLs.  Any example you find that works for an HTTP URL should also work for HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but https url is untrusted url.and i was not able to retrieve the image the from the url.But by using this:-[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] host]]; i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_a_synchronous_request) framework

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply......
i got the solution.
i had done in this way:-

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] host]];

    //  [theRequest addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       

    //  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];     
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

    if(theConnection) {
        self.activeDownload = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
```